# fetch all records from table A and not empty from table B

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 2 tables with following data

Table A

```
code  Desc
1     john
2     dave
3     mike
4     lily
5     cobe
6     rose
```

Table B

```
code    marks
1       30
2       35
3       40
5       29
```

RESULT TABLE

```
code   Desc   Marks
1      john      30
2      dave      35
3      mike      40
4      lily       0
5      cobe      29
6      rose       0
```

I have tried using left join but that displays only the records which are present in table B

Comment: A left join should have worked. Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` should work.  I think maybe you are trying to get the `0` values instead of the null-blanks?  If so, you need to use `COALESCE()`:

```
postgres=# select a.code,"Desc",coalesce("Marks",0) as "Marks"
from tablea a 
left join tableb b on a.code=b.code;
 code | Desc | Marks 
------+------+-------
    1 | john |    30
    2 | dave |    35
    3 | mike |    40
    4 | lily |     0
    5 | cobe |    29
    6 | rose |     0
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://www.enterprisedb.com)

Answer (score 0):

A left join will work, but you must be using `from students`. The `from` table is the "left" side of the join. See 
[Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)
 for an excellent visualization.

And use [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to turn the missing marks into 0.

```
select id, name, coalesce(mark, 0)
from students s
left join marks m on m.student_id = s.id
order by s.id;
```

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cd5e4b7296a3d0ff3dc3334d0d952eb2).

Comment: Venn diagrams are not an "excellent" visualization. [Say NO to Venn Diagrams](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/)  - what they **completely** miss is the fact that a JOIN might duplicate rows from one or more tables and that's what most people learning SQL are very confused about.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Most people are very confused about joins, full stop. ;) Why not use both? Those do a good job illustrating interleaving. Venn diagrams do a good job illustrating what "inner", "outer", "left", and "right" are referring to (something I never could keep straight before seeing them). This answer isn't for most people, it's about left joins, so venn diagrams it is. Thanks for the reference, very handy, I'll add it to my teaching aids.